# Meta query: get posts with value in a multidimensional array

Tags: get-posts, array, meta-query

I have a custom post type, Album, which has a custom field called 'tracklist'. Tracklist is a multidimensional array which contains a track title and track link, like so:

```
$tracklist = array(
  [0] => array(
    [title] => 'Stairway to Heaven'
    [link]  => 'stairway.mp3'
  )
  [1] => array(
    [title] => 'Battle of Evermore'
    [link]  => 'battle.mp3'
  )
);
```

I want to use get_posts to find all the albums with the song 'Stairway to Heaven.' Something like this (I know this won't work, but hopefully it will explain my intentions):

```
$albums = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'  => 'collection',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'   => 'tracklist',
      'value' => array(
        'key'   => 'track'
        'value' => array(
          'key'   => 'title',
          'value' => 'Starway to Heaven'
        )
      )
    )
  )
));
```

It's easy enough to use meta_query to look for a custom field that returns a single string, but in this case I'm looking a for a value buried a few levelsdeep. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not efficiently. You best bet is to use the `LIKE` statement, but it would fail for searches like "title", "link", "mp3" :)

I suggest you build your own serialization method. For example, store the tracklist as a string like this:

```
Track1 title
Track2 title
```

Notice the new line character  (`\n`). Use it to [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string into an array when you need to use the meta value.

Then you can have something like:

```
..
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'   => 'tracklist',
      'value' => 'Starway to Heaven',
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    )
  )
...
```

The download links can go into a separate meta record.